# How can I declare a nested types?

Tags: haskell

I have BoolExpr type and I want to declare VarAssociation type like this

```hs
data BoolExpr = Var Char |
                Const Bool |
                Not BoolExpr |
                And BoolExpr BoolExpr |
                Or BoolExpr BoolExpr |
                Impl BoolExpr BoolExpr |
                Eq BoolExpr BoolExpr |
                Xor BoolExpr BoolExpr
                deriving (Eq)

data VarAssociative = VarAssociative {unVar :: Var, unValue :: Bool}
```

But it is incorrect. How can I do this? I've tried to separate declaration of Var but it doesn't work too.

Comment: do be honest I can not really tell what you are trying to do - anyway it does not work because `Var` is not a type (it's a data-constructor/value) - you could either change this into `data VarAssociative = VarAssociative { unVar :: Char, unValue :: Bool }` or `data VarAssociative = VarAssociative { unVar :: BoolExpr, unValue :: Bool }`

Answer (score 0):

In a data declaration, all the new names to the left of the equality sign are new type names, while all the new names to the right of the equality sign are new computation names. So `BoolExpr` is a type, but `Var` is a computation, not a type.

Instead of the "type" `Var`, you could use the type which contains all the same fields as a fully-applied `Var` computation; in this case, that's just the one field, of type `Char`. So:

```
data VarAssociative = VarAssociative
    { unVar :: Char
    , unValue :: Bool
    }
```